# Extend OneToOne Doctrine annotation in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine, one-to-one

Is there a way to extend the behavior of the `OneToOne` Doctrine Annotation?

The idea is to add another parameter (optional)

Comment: As this is a `OneToOne` association, why it is not possible to add the parameter in one of the classes linked by the relation ?

Comment: That's the requirement that I have... To add another element to the OneToOne annotation.

Comment: Normally I had to add another custom property annotation, but I did not manage to find a helpful ressource on how to do this properly. For adding class or method custom annotations I found great tutorials, but nothing good on custom property annotations... So that's why now I need to add another optional parameter to the `OneToOne` annotation

Comment: And what exactly would this optional parameter do?